# jQuery add image inside of div tag

Tags: jquery

I have a div tag

```
<div id="theDiv">Where is the image?</div>
```

I would like to add an image tag inside of the div

End result:

```
<div id="theDiv"><img id="theImg"  src="theImg.png" />Where is the image?</div>
```

Answer (score 326, accepted):

Have you tried the following:

```
$('#theDiv').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="theImg.png" />')
```

Comment: I can't respond to Jose Basilio above (not enough rep) but append will put it AFTER "Where is the image?". Prepend will put it before.

Comment: I was about to upvote you for using prepend, but I noticed that you're missing '#' in your selector...

Comment: I jumped the gun with append. Good catch. +1

Comment: appendTo doesn't work...at least in my code and it wasn't the right one to use after I read it on the jQuery docs page even before posting this thread.

Comment: tried .append() and .html() to add the image tag, but image is not loading though the <img> tag appears with the source properly. Any suggestions over this ?

Comment: @AnoopGoudar Post a question here on SO with your code and perhaps we can help. It's really hard to debug something when we can't see the code :-)

Comment: @TopherFangio I have added the code and the hack I used to fix the issue I had. Please suggest if it can be done in a better way. But that fix is working for me now.

Answer (score 61):

my 2 cents:

```
$('#theDiv').prepend($('<img>',{id:'theImg',src:'theImg.png'}))
```

Comment: i like this answer cuz of the $('<img>') usage, was looking for it.

Comment: you can also add attributes after the $('<img').attr('id', 'theImg').attr('src', 'theImg.png')

Comment: isnt this the correct answer?

Answer (score 27):

```
$("#theDiv").append("<img id='theImg' src='theImg.png'/>");
```

You need to read the documentation [here](http://docs.jquery.com).

Answer (score 11):

If we want to change the content of `<div>` tag whenever the function `image()`is called, we have to do like this:

**Javascript**

```
function image() {
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.src = "/images/img1.gif";
    $('#image').html(img); 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="image"></div>
<div><a href="javascript:image();">First Image</a></div>
```

Comment: I suggest you to add some explanation.

Comment: If we want to change the content of <div>tag,whenever the function image()is called.
we have to do like this/

function image() {
 var img = document.createElement("IMG");
 img.src = "/images/img1.gif";
 $('#image').html(img);
}

<div id="image"></div>
<div><a href="javascript:image();">First Image</a></div>

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Manjeet Kumar's post (he didn't have the declaration)

```
var image = document.createElement("IMG");
image.alt = "Alt information for image";
image.setAttribute('class', 'photo');
image.src="/images/abc.jpg";
$("#TheDiv").html(image);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var img;
for (var i = 0; i < jQuery('.MulImage').length; i++) {
                var imgsrc = jQuery('.MulImage')[i];
                var CurrentImgSrc = imgsrc.src;
                img = jQuery('<img class="dynamic" style="width:100%;">');
                img.attr('src', CurrentImgSrc);
                jQuery('.YourDivClass').append(img);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the best way :

$(selector).prepend()