# Display the image right after upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image

I want to display the image right after uploading it. For this I added the function `$('#imageInput').on('change', function())` in the `.success()` function of ajax but it does not work. `alert("good")` pops "good" but `alert("better")` does not pop "better".

Any ideas how to achieve this?

JS:

```
function afterSuccess(data)
{

    if(data.indexOf('error')<0)
    {  alert ("good");
      $('#imageInput').on('change', function() {
            alert ("better");
            readPath(this);
            });  

    }
}
```

Comment: That's because you only create an event handler - you never fire it off.

Comment: the input doesnt change when you upload it.

Comment: @tymeJV Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

The `$('#imageInput').on('change', function() {...});` event does not fire because the upload field changes when the file is selected (pre-upload). The field does not change when the file is uploaded.

Update: In regards to your follow up question (see comments below), consider something like this, where the `data` array may vary depending on what is returned by your php script, and the insertion method may vary depending on your HTML layout (in this case, I assume that there is a  element you would be inserting the  into:

```
function afterSuccess(data)
{
  if(data.indexOf('error')<0)
   {
          var filepath = data['filepath'];
          $("#imageContainer").html("<img src="+filepath+"/>");
   } else {
       alert('Sorry, but an error occurred while uploading the image. Please try again');
   }
}
```

Comment: So what should I do to display the image right after upload?

Comment: Assuming that the `data` var contains the filename, you could use jQuery to insert an image element into the page body. There are a lot of methods you can use to do the insert (depending on your page structure), but one example is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941206/jquery-add-image-inside-of-div-tag

Comment: Cant I simply reload that div "#imageContainer"? If so, then how?(I am asking this because I do not want to return the filepath from upload.php for security reasons)

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. If you need to display the image file, passing the filepath (URL) of the image to the `<img>` element is required. Can you clarify what you do and don't want to do here?

Comment: The image.jpg gets updated on uploading the file(different image with same name is uploaded).Now I want to reload that div.

Comment: I would recommend reading up on how to handle AJAX calls. The jQuery API page for the ajax method is located here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, and another helpful page here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery--net-6289

Answer (score 0):

if the filename and path are returned properly, maybe this will work to display it?:

```
function afterSuccess(data)
{
  if(data.indexOf('error')<0)
    {  
          $("#desiredDiv").html("<img src="+path+"/>");
    }
}
```