# How to load division only using jquery in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

In the file upload after uploading the image I need to show immediately that image in the another division which is available in same page without refreshing full page I used `location.reload()` but that is reloading full page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery add image inside of div tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941206/jquery-add-image-inside-of-div-tag)

Comment: $("#theDiv").append("<img id='theImg' src='theImg.png'/>");

Comment: Possible duplicate of this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207575/how-to-preview-a-image-before-and-after-upload

Comment: by using ajax request i am sending image to server its saving in the database but it is not showing in the division until i reload my page

Comment: you are using Asp Upload or ajax Uploader ?

Comment: i am using ordinary html file upload

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax and you can load a portion of the page.

Check it out

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: by using ajax request i am sending image to server its saving in the database but it is not showing in the division until i reload my page

Answer (score 0):

You can see similar question related to it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
          <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
         <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
    </form>
</body>
```

[how to preview a image before and after upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207575/how-to-preview-a-image-before-and-after-upload)

Comment: by using ajax request i am sending image to server its saving in the database but it is not showing in the division until i reload my page

Comment: You need to make a ajax call of server to get URL from server via jquery and then it will show.

Comment: do u have any idea about loading division only without loading whole page

Comment: Put a devision with image tag and then get a url from ajax call of server and then put that url in division via code above. I think this should slove your problem.

Comment: but my url is looking like this http://localhost:14605/Home.aspx?id=mELirpUhRYksFj7k8%2fXBcQ%3d%3d#activityfeeds------activityfeeds is my div

Comment: I'm talking about image url not your webrowser url